# Backpack for Laravel : Redirection after login

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

In "Backpack for Laravel", where can I change the redirect after login?
By default, it redirects to /admin/dashboard

I tried modifying in app > Http > Middleware > RedirectifAuthenticated.php file but it doesn't work.

Ideas ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it modifying **$this->redirectTo = 'new redirect path / route / function';**, defining there the new route to which the user will be redirected once logged in, under **__construct()** method, in the file **app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php**.

If you need a redirect based on other parameters, or perform actions actions prior to redirecting after login, you can omit $this->redirectTo in construct(), and add the **authenticated()** method to that same file, which will override the original at *backpack\CRUD\app\Library\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php*

For example, in app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php:

```
/**
  * The user has been authenticated.
  *
  * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
  * @param mixed $user
  * @return mixed
  */
 protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
 {
     // get custom admin user prefered main section
     // return redirect(backpack_url($user_section));
 }
```